# Why is the definition of a Dwyer map so particular?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Recall that a functor $F : A \to B$ is said to be a [Dwyer map](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dwyer+map) if the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. $F$ is a [sieve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sieve) inclusion.
2. There exists a factorization of $F$ as $A \to W \to B$ where $W \to B$ is a cosieve inclusion and $A \to W$ is a sort of strong deformation retract.

(See the above nlab link for the precise definition of "strong deformation retract".)

**Question 0:**
Why are Dwyer maps defined that way?

It's kind of a strange definition in that the are 3 other classes of maps involved -- sieves, cosieves, and strong deformation retracts -- which are asked to fit together in a very particular way. It feels like some sort of Rube Goldberg machine!

---

In an attempt to approach Question 0, let's review what Dwyer maps are used for. The first place they show up is in the Thomason model structure, where they contain the cofibrations. Their main utility comes from the following two "cofibration-like" properties:

1. Dwyer maps are closed under cobase-change, transfinite composition, and retracts. (Say that the class of Dwyer maps is *cofibrantly closed*.)
2. If $A \to B$ is a Dwyer map and $A \to C$ is another functor, then the pushout of the resulting span is carried to a homotopy pushout by the geometric realization functor.

So in an attempt to approach Question 0, it seems natural to ask about how the 3 simpler classes of morphisms above fare with regard to these two properties.

**Question 1:** Is the class of co/sieves cofibrantly closed? How about strong deformation retracts? What about the class of morphisms generated by sieves, cosieves, and strong deformation retracts under composition?

**Question 2:** If $A \to B$ is a co/sieve and $A \to C$ is a functor, then is the resulting pushout square carried to a homotopy pushout by geometric realization? What if $A \to B$ is a stong deformation retract?

---

I *think* I care more about Property 2 and Question 2 than about Property 1 and Question 1 at the moment. Do I really need to understand Dwyer maps to study homotopy pushouts of categories, or can I get away with just thinking about co/sieves and strong deformation retracts separately?

Comment: In his _Asterisque_ manuscript (Lemma 5.1.12), Cisinski proves (2) in a way following Thomason which is separated out into different lemmas a bit more. I'm still struggling to see where one actually uses that $A \to B$ is a sieve inclusion though... (**EDIT:** Oh I see, this is needed to get the $V,V'$ of the proof in the first place...)

Comment: I am also generally quite confused by Dwyer maps, but the closest I've come to understanding them is that they're a categorical sort of "neighborhood deformation retract".  In classical algebraic topology, the Hurewicz cofibrations can be characterized as NDRs, meaning the inclusion of a (perhaps closed) subspace that has an open neighborhood of which it is a deformation retract.  So a Dwyer map is kind of like that where a "closed subspace" means a sieve and an "open subspace" means a cosieve.

Comment: @MikeShulman That is a really interesting comment!

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Cisinski actually uses the terminology "immersion ouverte" for a sieve inclusion and "immersion ferme" for a cosieve inclusion, which I think really brings out this analogy. By the way, if you get a chance to ask Dwyer about the history of Dwyer maps, do let me know. As far as I know they first show up in [Thomason's paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CTGDC_1980__21_3_305_0) (and Thomason calls them "Dwyer maps"), and it's kind of implied that he got the idea from conversations with Dwyer or something, but I'd be curious to know more.